# Why is research effort important?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Do you feel like being taken advantage of when the asker is sharing the question without sharing his efforts?
Does this feeling wane if the efforts the asker made are more confusing than doing it yourself?

I experienced it many times (no, I don't have links right here, and nitpicking wouldn't prove me wrong anyway) that after refraining from sharing my approach for complexity reasons and to see a solution outside the box, I was asked to share it. When I did, nobody answered the question, because of TL/DR Internet laziness.

It is clear, what I am saying (this is a discussion; there is no "asking"), you just don't like it, as you always do, just do disguise it behind nonsense phrases like "Unclear what is being asked" or "too broad" or whatever broad statement you could make.

According to *similar questions*, there is no similar question.

Comment: I can neither confirm

Comment: There isn't a feeling of accomplishment when I know i'm helping lazy uses keep being a lazy git

Comment: Is this a complaint or do we need to do/stop doing something?

Comment: *"because of TL/DR internet lazyness"* - [citation needed].

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Why is research important?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6560/31260)

Comment: By all means edit to clarify, but don't just whine.

Comment: @Vitalis Hommel I oppose canned reasons for closing questions, but I hardly understand what do you suggest or want to share if anything? It seems like you complain that despite your effort no-one answered your question, so why they asked you to share research to begin with - correct? Stay cool - most of my own questions I had to answer myself too. Its probably natural, unless your topic is very popular at the moment, and everyone jumps on it, or very easy to answer.

Comment: @sambul35 Might be.

Answer (score 15):

You need to share the research you have done, because you might have tried a couple of things already (otherwise, you [shouldn't even post the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4751173)). *We don't want to waste our time trying the same things you did.* You might have made a simple mistake in one of your options, or an altogether different approach might be necessary to solve your problem. Without you telling us what you did, we are forced to start from scratch.

Comment: And as additional benefit by sharing your research any future visitors who start their research with the same search criteria / idea / approach will now find the question and hopefully with a decent answer ...